# How to generate excel file using write-excel-file library when I need to map through elemenents of data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, export-to-excel

I need to generate excel report using write-excel-file library.
On simple mock data it works to me but in reality I need to provide data mapping through array of objects.
This is how array of objects looks like:

```
export const benefits = [
  {
    comment: "brak",
    companyCost: 90,
    luxmedType: {
      package: "Indywidualny",
      type: "Opieka standardowa",
      cost: 0
    },
    persons: [
      {
        name: "Jan",
        lastName: "Kowalski",
        cooperationForm: "b2b",
        type: "b2b"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    comment: "nic do skomentowania",
    companyCost: 50,
    luxmedType: {
      package: "Rodzinny",
      type: "Opieka rozszerzona",
      cost: 100
    },
    persons: [
      {
        name: "Tomasz",
        lastName: "Michalski",
        cooperationForm: "umowa o pracę",
        type: "pracownik"
      },
      {
        name: "Ewa",
        lastName: "Michalska",
        cooperationForm: "null",
        type: "partner"
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

Data should be mapped through benefits array and inside persons array. I have tried firstly to map through benefits array but it does not return any values in excel. Can You please suggest how to solve it ?

```
import "./styles.css";
import writeXlsxFile from "write-excel-file";
import { benefits } from "./benefits";

const HEADER_ROW = [
  {
    value: "Name and Last Name",
    fontWeight: "bold"
  },
  {
    value: "Contract Type",
    fontWeight: "bold"
  },
  {
    value: "Employee/Partner/Kid",
    fontWeight: "bold"
  },
  {
    value: "Package Type",
    fontWeight: "bold"
  },
  {
    value: "Employee Cost",
    fontWeight: "bold"
  },
  {
    value: "300B Cost",
    fontWeight: "bold"
  },
  {
    value: "Comments",
    fontWeight: "bold"
  }
];

const DATA_ROW_BENEFITS = benefits.map((element) => {
  return [
    {
      type: String,
      value: "józek"
    },
    {
      type: String,
      value: "Contract Type"
    },
    {
      type: String,
      value: "Employee/Partner/Kid"
    },
    {
      type: String,
      value: "Package Type"
    },
    {
      type: Number,
      value: 50
    },
    {
      type: Number,
      value: 100
    },
    {
      value: "Comment"
    }
  ];
});

const data = [HEADER_ROW, DATA_ROW];

export default function App() {
  const createExcelReport = async () => {
    console.log("click");
    await writeXlsxFile(data, {
      fileName: "benefits.xlsx"
    });
  };
```

I have also prepared codesandbox so it will be easier to look and check:
https://codesandbox.io/s/thirsty-mccarthy-5b40tj?file=/src/App.js:1359-1573

If You have also other working libraries to export excel files I'm open, I tried few others but they didn't work.

thanks